# What is the fastest way to find value that appears only once in a list?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I have tried using

```
nums = [#10000 items of type int]
arr = numpy.array(nums)
for value,count for collections.Counter(arr).items():
   if count == 1:
       return value
```

but it is too slow. Is there any faster way to solve this.

time 200ms

Comment: `Counter(nums)` should be faster.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got this using `np.unique(..., return_counts=True)`:

```
import numpy as np

# Synthesise array...
arr = np.random.randint(0,8, (10000), np.int32)

# ... with one unique value
arr[5000] = 9
```

And now time the code:

```
%%timeit  
...: v,c = np.unique(arr, return_counts=True) 
...: np.argwhere(c==1) 

164 µs ± 672 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

The array `c` looks like this:

```
array([1284, 1224, 1311, 1185, 1207, 1278, 1233, 1277,    1])
```

and the index of the unique value:

```
np.argwhere(c==1)                                                                                                                               
Out[62]: array([[8]])
```

Comment: Perhaps you want to state a bit more clearly that you are suggesting to use `np.unique()` as I was about to write another answer ;-)

Comment: @MarkSetchell thanks it improved my time. For better output you can flatten the array to 1D then get element[0]

Answer (score 0):

you can create a reverse dictionary based on frequency

```
import numpy as np
import collections

nums=np.random.randint(2,100,10000)
nums[np.random.randint(0,10000-1)]=1 # set a unique value with one
freq = collections.Counter(nums) # get frequencies
revFreq = {v: k for k, v in freq.items()} # reverse the dictionary so each frequency points to its value

revFreq[1] # get the value that appeared one time
1
```

Comment: This approach is bound to be much slower (there is a lack of short-circuiting as soon as the value with count == 1 is found), much less memory efficient since it is creating an additional, potentially large, `dict`, and it may not give the same result as OP, because if multiple uniques are found, this will give the last found, not the first, as key must be unique in the arrays and later one will overwrite the previous.